# SQL statement to get distinct data

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
ID | user_id | name      | active
1  | 1       | Profile 1 | f
2  | 1       | Profile 2 | t
3  | 2       | Profile 3 | f
4  | 2       | Profile 4 | f
5  | 3       | Profile 5 | f
```

I'm using PostgreSQL. In my application,`users` can create multiple `profiles` and I want to select last distinct **inactive profiles** created by  each user. Also, if there is an `active` profile belongs to that user, it should not select any profile from that user -- that was the hard part for me.

What kind of SQL statement I should use in order to get the following results?

```
4  | 2       | Profile 4 | f
5  | 3       | Profile 5 | f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) with [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS).
Assuming a proper `boolean` type for active:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
       id, user_id, name, active
FROM   profiles p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM profiles
   WHERE  user_id = p.user_id
   AND    active               -- exclude users with any active profiles
   )
ORDER  BY user_id, id DESC;
```

Probably fastest and cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct on` syntax works very well for this:

```
select distinct on (user_id) id, user_id, name, active
from t
where active = 'f'
order by user_id, id desc;
```

EDIT:

To avoid an active profile, it probably easier to go to analytic functions:

```
select id, user_id, name, active
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, active order by id desc) as seqnum,
             max(case when active = 'f' then 0 else 1 end) as numActives
      from t
     ) t
where numActives = 0 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It does, expect it also select rows with users who has an active profile.

Comment: @ErenCAY . . . Yes, that makes it hard to use `distinct on`.  See the edited version.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It might be better to use `bool_or(active) as anyActive` instead of `max(case when active = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as numActives`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Also you do not need to `partition by user_id, active`. `partition by user_id` will be enough.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko . . . True about the first point, although I prefer to use more standard constructs when I can.  As for the second one, I thought about that and it also works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is OK to use more standart constructs, but still you save a mistake in `max(case when active = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as numActives`. It will return `1` if any record has `active = 'f'`. You need `case when active then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @ErenCAY: The first query forgets about active profiles and the second one has the logic backwards.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right. Also, second one seems like hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/de3c4/1)

```
select distinct on (user_id)
    id, user_id, name, active
from
    t
    inner join
    (
        select user_id
        from t
        group by user_id
        having not bool_or(active)
    ) s using(user_id)
order by user_id, id desc
```